# Preventing "not wrapped in act(...)" Jest warning when state update doesn't affect UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, testing-library

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to prevent the "not wrapped in act(...)" warning thrown by Jest/testing-library when I have nothing to assert after the state update that causes the warning happens, or if I should just ignore this warning.

Suppose I have this simple component:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {getData} from 'services';

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [arr, setArr] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const {items} = await getData();
      setArr(items);
    })();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {!(arr.length > 0) && <p>no array items</p>}
      {arr.length > 0 && (
        <ul>
          {arr.map(item => (
            <li key={item.id}>{item.name}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

Suppose I want to simply test that this component renders okay even if `getData()` doesn't return any data for me.

So I have a test like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import {getData} from 'services';
import {render, screen} from 'testUtils';
import MyComponent from './MyComponent';

jest.mock('services', () => ({
  getData: jest.fn(),
}));

it('renders', () => {
  getData.mockResolvedValue({items: []});

  render(<MyComponent />);

  expect(screen.getByText('no array items')).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

This test will pass, but I'll get the "not wrapped in act(...)" warning because the test will finish before `getData()` has a chance to finish.

In this case, the response from `getData()` sets `arr` to the same value (an empty array) as I have initially set it to at the top of the component. As such, my UI doesn't change after the async function completes—I'm still just looking at a paragraph that says "no array items"—so I don't really have anything I can assert that would wait for the state update to complete.

I can `expect(getData).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)`, but that doesn't wait for the state to actually be updated after the function call.

I have attempted an arbitrary pause in the test to allow time for `setArr(items)` to happen:

```
it('renders', async () => {
  getData.mockResolvedValue({items: []});

  render(<MyComponent />);

  expect(screen.getByText('no array items')).toBeInTheDocument();
  
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));

  expect(screen.getByText('no array items')).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

But that doesn't seem to help, and I'm honestly not sure why.

**Is there a way to handle this situation by modifying only the test?**

I am sure I could fix the problem by refactoring MyComponent, e.g., by passing `arr` to MyComponent as a prop and moving the `getData()` call to a parent component, or creating some custom prop used only for testing that would skip the `getData()` call altogether, but I don't want to be modifying components purely to avoid warnings in tests.

I am using [testing-library/react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@testing-library/react), v11.2.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `findByText` (a combination of `getByText` and `waitFor`) to ensure all updates have happened when the assertion resolves.

```js
it('renders', async () => {
    getData.mockResolvedValue({items: []});
    render(<MyComponent />);
    expect(await screen.findByText('no array items')).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I was aware of `findBy` and have used it plenty, but I guess I didn't know it would necessarily wait for state updates. The docs I have been referring to (https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async) make it seem like it just waits for async DOM changes, but in this case the DOM doesn't actually change (even if the component's render function does get called again), so I guess I didn't think that would work. I'll have to remember this going forward :)

Answer (score 0):

@juliomalves's answer is spot on.
However, I had to put this `await` in my `beforeEach`:

```js
import {render, fireEvent} from '@testing-library/react';
import MyComponent from './MyComponent';

...

describe('MyComponent should', () => {
  let getByText, getByTestId, getAllByTestId, getByLabelText;
  beforeEach(async () => {
    let findByText;
    ({
      getByText,
      getByTestId,
      getAllByTestId,
      getByLabelText,
      findByText,
    } = render(<MyComponent {...props} />));

    // Have this here to avoid warnings because of setting state variables
    await findByText('no array items');
  })

  ...
});
```